# If and else without curly brackets

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

Is it possible to have an if condition with curly brackets and else conditions without brackets? Also what is the good practice to format it , should there be a new line after else keyword?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
{
    fuDocumentUploader.CssClass = CssClass;
    CssClass = null;
}
else txtDocumentUploadLink.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: This question appears to be asking about a practice in general, with the code snippet serving merely as a generic example, rather than for suggestions to improve the code. Questions about best practices in general are off-topic, as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to have an if condition with curly brackets and else conditions without brackets?

Or course it's possible. You don't even need new lines and can write everthing like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass)) { fuDocumentUploader.CssClass = CssClass; CssClass = null; } else txtDocumentUploadLink.Text = string.Empty;
```

But you should ask yourself these two questions:

- *Do I want my code to be readable/clean/consistent?* and
- *Do I want to reduce the possibility of future errors?*

If both answers are *yes* then you should use curly braces. Doesn't this look cleaner? You see right away that there is an `else` and what it does.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
{
    fuDocumentUploader.CssClass = CssClass;
    CssClass = null;
}
else 
{
    txtDocumentUploadLink.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: How the addition of brackets for the "else" can reduce the possibility of future errors, please ?

Comment: @aguetat because you won't do this: `else txtDocumentUploadLink.Text = string.Empty; txtOtherLink.Text = string.Emtpy;` which would be adding more _lines_ to the `else` that are no longer part of it. Then you wonder why it doesn't work as expected.